# Which of these two methods returns the pointer to a structure member

Tags: c

```
struct
{
   Uint32 oneval;
   Uint32 twoval;
} mydata_t;

Uint32 *valptr;
mydata_t astruct;

valptr = &asturct.twoval;

valptr = &(astruct.twoval);
```

Which of these gives a Uint32 pointer to twoval ??

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this yourself?

Comment: well i programmed   &(astruct.twoval) and I think that is correct but I am not getting correct results.

Comment: could be other other code that is erroneous also

Comment: Thanks, I know it is a ridiculous simple question as do those who downvoted but I just couldn't find the direct answer in my favorite c books.  I guess I should have figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence

They both do as the "." has a higher precedence than "&"